# What does Jump to means in callgrind?

Tags: performance, assembly, valgrind

I have `callgrind` profiling results of a small test, I would like to find performance bottlenecks, so sorting by `self` I found a C method that has 16 % of `self` and 16% of `inclusive`. Now Opening the Assembly code for that function I have found many `Jump 9450 of 118000 times to 0x507C8C`. However it is a small C function.

I wonder if those Jumps in Assembly code are what causing the performance to drop ?

Comment: Before these Jumps .... There is a `jne: jump if not equal` assembly instruction. Which means that out of 118000 times this instruction has been called, 9450 times the condition has not been met.

Comment: However I still do not understand that in terms of this method performance